# Splitting nested array sent from android to php

Tags: java, php, android, arrays, json

I am sending JSON Objects which contain converted `ArrayLists`. For the most part everything works fine except on the PHP page.

If I use:

```
if($_POST)
{
echo "Something was sent";
$obj = array();
$JSON_Entry = $_POST["Entry"];

$body = json_decode($JSON_Entry, true);

foreach ($body as $key => $value) 
{
   echo $value;            
}
```

I get the response in android emulator logs;

```
Something was sent[SalesMade [id=0, product_description=Beer, qty=2, unit=3, total=6.0]]
```

But when I try to separate the array using:

```
foreach($value as $column => $row)
{
   echo  $row;
}
```

I get an `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` error. Is it because I converted the `ArrayList` to a JSON object before posting?

Comment: If the first code works, then it looks like the JSON is not being formed correctly on the client side. `$body` just contains a string "[SalesMade [id=0, product_description=Beer, qty=2, unit=3, total=6.0]]" which is indeed an invalid argument for `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to json_decode() $value, then you can foreach() through it.